# How to output in ACIS formats like .sat or .sab?

Tags: python, export

I am currently writing a program that is outputting a 3D model into a simulation software. Currently I am ouputting in .stl file format for the object using the blender python function that does this extremely easily. I have to have all of this running in the background for various reason so I also have to set up scripting on the simulation software. In their GUI they take in .stl files just fine, but after trying to write a script for it and getting errors I contacted them with the unfortunate news that my file format needs to be ACIS format like .sat or .sab when writing scripts and if I want to use .stl I have to use the GUI. This is not doable for me so here is my questions.

After a little bit of quick googling I can't seem to find any good solutions to get blender to output in the .sat or .sab file formats. Is there any easy solution to this like a plugin or will I need to use an external software to convert this? As far I have been reading, with how I have my object made it shouldn't be a hard conversion but if it's possible in blender I will take that to minimize the amount of software I am using.

Thanks for the help in advance, I am fairly new to Blender and especially when it comes to exporting in python. I will also continue to look into it further once I get home later today so hopefully I will figure it out.

Comment: `.sat` and `.sab` are CAD file formats for holding solid based geometry data. Blender doesn't import or export those formats because it doesn't even have a concept of solid based geometry representations.

Comment: Also if you already converted them to STL there really is no way back, through Blender or otherwise, data has already been converted to mesh format.